# Transport level information does not match with SOAP Message namespace URI error

Tags: apache-axis, soap1.2

I'm getting below error while posting soap message to other third party Vendor. Soap versions are same at both sides and 1.2. Could anyone suggest?

```
<env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:soapenc="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-encoding">
    <env:Body>
        <env:Fault>
            <axis2ns1:Code xmlns:axis2ns1="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
            <axis2ns1:Value>env:Receiver</axis2ns1:Value>
            </axis2ns1:Code>
            <axis2ns1:Reason xmlns:axis2ns1="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
                <env:Text xml:lang="en">org.apache.axiom.soap.SOAPProcessingException: Transport level information does not match with SOAP Message namespace URI</env:Text>
            </axis2ns1:Reason>
        </env:Fault>
    </env:Body>
</env:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 0):

See

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AXIS2-5928

Or

https://wso2.org/jira/browse/ESBJAVA-4873

Or

https://wso2.org/jira/browse/ESBJAVA-4873

This usually happens when SOAP 1.2 message has been sent to a SOAP 1.1 binding endpoint or vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure the `Content-Type` in the headers of this request is `application/soap+xml` and not `text/xml` as the latter is used for SOAP version 1.1.